# Given an undirected connected graph, how many orientations would maintain acyclicity

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given an undirected connected simple graph $G=(V,E)$ there are $2^{|E|}$ orientations. How many of these orientations are acyclic?

Comment: If you have a cyclic graph, then the answer is simple because you can choose any orientation in which all edges are not pointed the same direction. If you have a graph where all cycles involve a disjoint set of edges, the answer is similarly simple. But if cycles share edges the answer is much more complicated.

Comment: @user2566092 Does it make any difference that $G$ is a simple graph? When cycles shared edges, are there any sufficient conditions with which the number of acyclic orientations is known ? (i.e., in/out degrees of the vertices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a research paper from 1972 which addresses this question. Let $\chi(G, \lambda)$ be the chromatic polynomial. Then $(-1)^{V} \chi(G, -1)$ is the number of acyclic orientations of $G$, your graph. I let $V$ be the vertex count of $G$. This is Theorem 1.3 of the paper.

http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/18.pdf

Comment: How easy is it to compute the chromatic polynomial for a graph?

Comment: I came across this while researching. However, It is too difficult to me as I am not mathematician and have no good knowledge in graph-theoretic notions. I dont know what is chromatic polynomial or how we compute it.  This said, seems I need to understand the paper to come up with the acyclic orientations. ah !

Comment: It's NP-Hard to compute the chromatic polynomial. That being said, for a small graph, you may be able to do it by eye-balling it. The term $\lambda$ represents the number of colors. There is another paper I found for computing the Chromatic Polynomial: http://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/SeniorProjectArchive/2009/fouts.pdf

Comment: @ml0105 Are you aware of anything related to the number of single source single sink orientations? For instance, an upper bound or the exact number of given the chromatic polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Very old, but for the sake of completeness, yes, it is well known that we can count

$$ \text{AO}(G) = (-1)^{|V(G)|}\mathcal{X}_G(-1) = T_G(2,0)$$

where $\mathcal{X}_G$ denotes the chromatic polynomial of $G$, and $T_G$ denotes the *Tutte polynomial* of $G$. You can find a number of papers discussing these results, but the proof of the second inequality is usually done separately from the equality between the Tutte polynomial at $(0,2)$. Tutte polynomial is usually defined on matroids and worked backwards (since any graph $G$ admits a graphic matroid $M(G)$, anything true for $M(G)$ is true for $G$; ie, matroids are more general); there are a number of well-known TG-invariants, of which your question asks about just one. Another is $T_G(0,2)$, which counts the number of *totally cyclic orientations* instead.

The proofs for each are scattered about, but can dig them up at request.